# What are the use-cases for Sass color functions?

Tags: css, sass, colors

I've been a dev for 5 years and in every project, I was handed a design that needed to be implemented. I didn't have a choice in what colors I used - I just had to match the designs.

I'm trying to level up my understanding of SASS and practiced some of the color functions such as `color.scale()` and `color.adjust()`. I'm having a hard time finding any examples of *when* these things could be used. For example, if a div has a background that is slightly transparent in the designs, it would make sense to use one of these functions to make the background less opaque without having to declare a new color but I can't find any other use-cases for these properties/functions.

As a front end developer, why would I need the color functions provided by Sass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@use 'sass:color';

button {
  background-color: $color-main;
  &:hover {
    background-color: color.darken($color-main, 10%);
  }
}
```

This is just one example of one function, but it's a start :)